# Passing dependencies alongside other services in ngDialog - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, dependencies, ng-dialog

I'm opening a dialog which is sorting some of my elements. It has it's own controller and uses some of mutual services.

```
$scope.openSortDialog = function(category) {
  ngDialog.open({
    template: 'views/forms/sort.html',
    resolve: {
      category: category
    },
    controller: 'SortController',
    controllerAs: 'sort'
  });
};
```

I would like to keep SortController in other file as it's pretty big. But the problem is the **resolve** which I'm using to let SortController know which category is being sorted.

These are SortController dependencies:

```
.controller('SortController', function($scope, SharedService, ngDialog) {...
```

I have added the **resolve** just now as I am refactoring and have no idea how to include that dependency. What I did so far is put the category being sorted in SharedService which Sort has access to. But I'd like to have more direct route.

So the question is, how do I get **resolve** dependencies alongside controller dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$scope.openSortDialog = function(category) {
    ngDialog.open({
        template: 'views/forms/sort.html',
        controller: 'SortController',
        controllerAs: 'sort'
        resolve: {
            category: function () {
                return category;
            }
        }
}



.controller('SortController', ['$scope', 'category', 'SharedService', 'ngDialog',
    function($scope, category, SharedService, ngDialog) {...
```